# Pandas not importing excel changes

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am working in a python/django project in which I import some data from an Excel file.

The simplified view in which I need the import is:

urls.py

```
re_path(r'^product_push/', sick_data_views.Products_List_upload, name='product-push')
```

views.py

```
def ID_push():
    Products.objects.all().delete()
    df = product.importDataFrameProducts()
    print(df)
    data = Products(
                        ID = str(df['ID'].tolist()).replace("'",'\"'),
    )
    data.save()

def Products_List_upload(request):
    ID_push()
    return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

models.py

```
class Products(models.Model):
    ID = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
```

lists.py

```
class product:
    def __init__(self, excel_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"\\A_Products.xlsx"):
        self.__df =  self.importDataFrameExamplesList(excel_path)

    def importDataFrameExamplesList(self, excel_path):
        # Load json
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_path, keep_default_dates=False)
        return df

    def importDataFrameProducts(self):
        return self.__df
```

---

When I run the server, the importation process runs and I get the correct output:
The views call lists.py and updates the values. Let's say:

```
ID
1
2
3
```

But if I change the Excel file to other values, like:

```
ID
4
2
3
```

If I run localhost:8000/product_push, the importation return the older values of the Excel file (1,2,3).
I don't need to update automatically, but when I run the push url, I should be able to get the updated values.
Does panda store some variable in cache? Because I can only solve this problem after I rerun the server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if values update if you force refresh the page (Shift+Ctrl+R in Chrome), this should ignore the cashed content, and we can see if that's the issue. Pandas does not have any cash, but django probably does

Comment: @black_fm No, it wasn't the case. I still receive the old values, even though I had updated the excel file.

Comment: You are calling `importDataFrameExamplesList` on init, but on `product_push` you call `importDataFrameProducts` which just returns existing dataframe.

Comment: @black_fm Thanks, it worked. Sorry for the silly mistake.